# how to make that complex css selection in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to change that element whose class CSS is:

**`.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small`**

in jquery.

$(".ac-container input:checked .... missing part")

How do I select such element ?

Comment: The same syntax should work in jQuery.

Comment: It's the same: http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

Comment: That's called a _selector_, not a class.

Comment: Try it. Just try actually doing it.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery supports the same selectors that CSS does, with a couple of obscure differences.
That selector will work fine.